# How to connect the ESP32 Wrover Cam (WiFi Cam)?

Tags: c, arduino, camera, esp32

I uploaded this code in WiFi Cam example

```
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <ESPmDNS.h>
#include "esp_system.h"
#include <esp32cam.h>

static auto HQVGA = esp32cam::Resolution::find(240, 160);  
static auto QVGA = esp32cam::Resolution::find(320, 240);
static auto WQVGA = esp32cam::Resolution::find(400, 240);  
static auto VGA = esp32cam::Resolution::find(640, 480);  
static auto SVGA = esp32cam::Resolution::find(800, 600);

const char *ssid = "***";
const char *password = "***";
const char *dns = "camara";

WebServer servidor(80);


void conectaWiFi(){

    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Connectando a la red: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);

    WiFi.persistent(false); //Permite que la configuracion del Wifi no sea afectada.
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);    //Configura el Wifi en modo estacion
    WiFi.begin(ssid,password);      
 
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);       
        Serial.print(".");
    }

    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi conectado");
    Serial.println("Direccion IP: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    Serial.println("Direccion MAC: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.macAddress());
    //http://camara.local   //Servidor dns que sustituye a la IP (solo funciona con 
    Linux o IOS) Para windows se requiere software adicional

    if (!MDNS.begin(dns)) {
          Serial.print("Se configuro el DNS: http://");
          Serial.print(dns);
          Serial.println(".local/");

    }
    else{
        MDNS.addService("http", "tcp", 80); 
    } 

}

void error404() {
    servidor.send(200, "text/plain", "Error pagina no encontrada");  
}

void servirImagen() {

  auto frame = esp32cam::capture();
  if (frame == nullptr) {
    servidor.send(503, "", "");

    return;
  }
   Serial.printf("IMAGEN TOMADA %dx%d %db\n", frame->getWidth(), frame->getHeight(),
                static_cast<int>(frame->size()));

  servidor.setContentLength(frame->size());
  servidor.send(200, "image/jpeg");
  WiFiClient client = servidor.client();
  frame->writeTo(client);
}

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  using namespace esp32cam;

  Config configuracion;
  configuracion.setPins(pins::AiThinker);
  configuracion.setResolution(QVGA);
  configuracion.setBufferCount(5);  //Establece el numero de imagenes en el buffer
  configuracion.setJpeg(80);

  bool ok = Camera.begin(configuracion); //Inicializa la camara con la configuracion         
  previa
  Serial.println(ok ? "CAMERA OK" : "Error al inicializar la camara");

  conectaWiFi();

  servidor.on("/imagen.jpg", servirImagen); //En la funcion servirImagenes se creara la 
  pagina /imagen.jpg

  servidor.onNotFound(error404);

  servidor.begin();

  Serial.println("Servidor iniciado");

  }

void loop() {
  servidor.handleClient();
}
```

The code above compiles without problems, but the access to the camera shows as failed, I checked the error code but it still does not work (Sorry for not be able to post images because of my profile level haha, I put a image link instead).

[Error Image in Arduino Serial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a02Mi.png)

I compiled with this parameters:

[Arduino Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYKMI.png)

This is the ESP32 Wrover:

[My ESP32 CAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg64P.jpg)

Thank you in advance for the help...

Answer (score 0):

One of four possible problems:

- you may have the wrong pinout for the board you've connected your camera to. Try the each of the other pinouts the library supports. I would try this first as it's the easiest thing to do, though time consuming. You'll need to change the line `configuracion.setPins(pins::AiThinker);` to use other pin definitions.
- your camera may not be installed correctly. It's very easy to misalign the tiny cable for the camera. Double check this to make sure it's completely inserted and is seated correctly. From your photo it looks like it's seated properly but it's worth reinstalling it. If you try changing the pin configuration, make sure you go back to the original before you reseat the camera.
- you may be using an unsupported camera. It looks like your camera came with the board so this is unlikely, but possible.
- it's possible your camera or board is defective.

If the firmware that was originally installed on the camera worked then it's probably the pinout.